# How to iterate over array in object with async pipe and dynamic property?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have two objects `layers$` and `arrayByLayerId$` that I get asynchronously in my component, the structure of the objects is as following :

```
interface Layer {
   id: number;
   ...
}
```

```
{
   1: []
   2: []
   ...
}
```

Is there a way to iterate over `arrayByLayerId$` arrays with the async pipe in the template like something below (the syntax is not correct it's just to illustrate what I try to achieve) :

```
<div *ngFor="let layer of layers$ | async"
     [attr.id]="layer.id">

    <my-component *ngFor="let array of arrayByLayerId$[layer.id] | async" [array]="array"><my-component/>
</div>
```

Thanks !

Comment: `doesn't work` mean nothing. Are you sure that  `arrayByLayerId$[layer.id] | async` is actually working?

Comment: Needs to be put though async pipe before member access `[layer.id]`

Comment: I guess you could use eg. `foo$ = combineLatest([layers$, arrayByLayerId$])` and then `foo$ | async`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayByLayerId$` does not have a value yet before you access its "layer.id" property. It should be like this :

```
 <my-component *ngFor="let array of (arrayByLayerId$ | async)[layer.id]" [array]="array"><my-component/>
```